# How Unsubscribe from Lambda Event

Tags: c#

How can i unsubscribe from this lamda event?

```
Button1Clicked += () => Results(Result.Nothing);
```

This Doesn't work:

```
Button1Clicked -= () => Results(Result.Nothing);
```

thank you all

alternatively it is possible to do :

```
Button1Clicked += DoSomething;
Button1Clicked -= DoSomething;

private void DoSomething()
{
  do something
}
```

but passing a parameter, something like:

```
Button1Clicked += DoSomething(Result.Nothing)

private void DoSomething( Result.Nothing)
{
  do something
}
```

Thank you all

Comment: don't use anonymous functions to subscribe to events if you have to unsubscribe from the event at some later point in your code.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsofts Documentation on [Event Subscribing and Unsubscribing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events).

> You cannot easily unsubscribe from an event if you used an anonymous function to subscribe to it. To unsubscribe in this scenario, go back to the code where you subscribe to the event, store the anonymous function in a delegate variable, and then add the delegate to the event. We recommend that you don't use anonymous functions to subscribe to events if you have to unsubscribe from the event at some later point in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers point out, you cannot unsubscribe easily from an anonymous function.

Instead, you can create an event handler with extra parameters

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { button_Click(sender, e, "This is From Button1"); };
}

void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string message)
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Local Functions they can be unsubscribed and capture variables.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        var toCapture = "Hello World";
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Bar += OnBar;
        
        void OnBar(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(toCapture);
        }
        
        foo.DoBar();
        foo.Bar -= OnBar;
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public EventHandler Bar;
    
    public void DoBar() => Bar.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

eg.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/AOwOm9